# It sounds like "are" is eaten in "you're", is this a common accent or my mis listening?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, listening

I am not a native English speaker, so I have some difficulties on catching some pronunciation in spoken English.

This guy is lecturing (https://youtu.be/_nRtCVJIToA?t=251)

> You had an idea, you had a target, if "you're" going all the way, it means you're not stopping

where "you're" sounds like "you" without "are"

same situation happens again (same video, another time stamp)

> get out of my way if you're trying to stop me.

Is this his own accent or my mislistening?

Note: I am aware that "you're" is contraction of "you are", I have no difficulties on reading, writing, speaking when I encounter "you're" and "you are". I just have some difficulties on catching the "'re".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the contraction of you are, that is, **you're** is said fast in a sentence, it sounds like the e in the interjection er preceded by a y: yer. This is typical in American English.

This is not a true phonetic or phonemic description.

Answer (score 0):

The lecturer is Canadian, with a subtle but noticeable accent to me as a midwestern American. The thing you're noticing appears to be part of his dialect; you're not imagining it, although I probably wouldn't have noticed it myself.